# in sculpt mode, is there a way to hide one of the parts and keep the mirror modification applied?

Tags: sculpt

I'm trying to sew the pants, but it's difficult to sew the inside, without hiding the other part, but when I apply one part to the other that is hidden, it doesn't receive application...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sculpt mode, you can press <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, and then drag a box around what you want to see. Then everything outside of the box will become invisible. Then you can sculpt, and when your done, you can press <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> again to unhide everything. Not exactly sure if this will fix your problem, but I hope it helps.

Here is where you get to it if you don't want to use the shortcut key:
[image]

Comment: exactly that... can you tell me where I can find this without using shortcut?

Comment: Yes. I just edited my comment. See the attached screenshot. You Click on View, View Regions, Clipping Regions.

Comment: thank you dude..

Comment: Glad I could help!